# Adding List<CustomClass> into a JSONObject, adds Address to the JSONObject

Tags: java, spring, parsing

H, I am trying to add List into JSONObject(org.json.simple.jsonobject), and when i print the JSONObject, I see the address being added to the JSONObject.
When i try to parse the JSONObject in another method, i get Parse Exception, which is quite natural, because, My JSON Object somehow looks like this:

```
{"firstKey":"key1",
 "secondKey":"secondKey",
"customKey":Ljava@23422}
```

How do I save my List, into a JSONObject:

```
{ "firstKey":"key1",
"customKey":[{"name":"Lucifer", "lastName":"Geralt"}]}
```

Please help with your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to solve, please refer to this solution, if you face something similar:

```
JSONObject jsonobject= new JSONObject();
ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
List<User> user= repository.findAll();
String s= mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
eventMessageProperties.put("userList", s);
//to Parse
mapper.readValue((String)thingObject.get("userList"), new 
TypeReference<List<User>>(){});
```